# I can't see what's wrong with my Java code?

Tags: java

I am making a program that puts all data from one array, into a different array, backwards.

So, if

```
String[] originalArray = {"you", "see", "I"};
```

then it should transfer that into a new array like this:

```
String[] newArray = new String[3];

newArray = "I", "see", "you"
```

Here's my code.

```
public class ReverseArray {
public static void reverse() {
    String[] originalArray = {"cool", "really", "are", "You"};
    String[] newArray = {"", "", "", ""};

    for(int b = 0; b < newArray.length; b++) {
        for(int a = 3; a < -1; a--) {
            newArray[b] = originalArray[a];
        }
    }

    for(int c = 0; c < newArray.length; c++) {
        System.out.print(newArray[c] + "+");
    }

   }
}
```

I'm not sure what is wrong. When I try to print it out, it just prints out (+ + + +)

I've tried changing

```
String[] newArray = {"", "", "", ""};
```

to

```
String[] newArray = new String[4];
```

But it just made then output as

```
null
```

Any help?

Comment: Try to use a debugger, or do the problem by hand, and then copy the steps into your code.

Comment: You seem to be assigning `newArray[b]` multiple different values from `originalArray[a]`...

Comment: a=3 and because 3 < -1 = FALSE, Your loop stops immediatelly.

Comment: Can you explain how do you think your code works? Try to read it out loud.

Comment: @John have a look at the answer..

Answer (score 3):

Your problem is in your inner loop...

```
for (int a = 3; a < -1; a--) {
```

Read this out loud...

- `a` equals `3`
- while `a` is less than `-1` do `a--`

See where it falls down, the `for-loop` will only run while `a` is `-1`, but you've initialised it to `3`

You can actually get away with a single loop, for example...

```
String[] newArray = new String[originalArray.length];

for (int index = 0; index < newArray.length; index++) {
    newArray[index] = originalArray[originalArray.length - index - 1];
}
```

Basically this uses the `index` value for both arrays, but adjust the `originalArray` so it moves from the end instead of the start, as one possible solution ;)

Comment: Body of this loop also doesn't seem right. Anyway +1 for posting explanation of problem instead of just solution.

Comment: @Pshemo Yeah the double loop is completely wrong, but that's just me ;)

Comment: Nice answer. I liked the "Read this out loud".

Comment: @JosEdu Always read my code aloud when it doesn't work...drives everyone in office nuts... ;)

Answer (score 1):

An alternative way using [Collections.reverse()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#reverse%28java.util.List%29):

```
List<String> list = Arrays.asList("cool", "really", "are", "You");
System.out.println(list);
Collections.reverse(list);
System.out.println(list);
```

Output:

```
[cool, really, are, You]

[You, are, really, cool]
```

Answer (score 0):

Okay, so the steps are the following:

You have an array `A` of size `X`. You want to put these elements in an array `B` of size `X`. So basically what you want is that the element in `A[0]` (the first element) is in the last position of `B`, being `B[2]`. To do this, you need to calculate the "reverse" index.

So first you loop over your array:

```
for(int index = 0; index < A.length;index++)
{
    String thisElement = A[index];
}
```

Next, you want to put it in the other array at the last position, right? So then you need to take the length of that array, minus the current index.

```
for(int index = 0; index < A.length;index++)
{
    String thisElement = A[index];
    // The other index
    int otherIndex = (B.length - 1) - index; // We do -1 because we have zero-indexing.
    B[otherIndex] = thisElement;
}
```

This should now contain all your elements in reverse order.

## Some things you did wrong

I've tried changing

```
String[] newArray = {"", "", "", ""};
```

to

```
String[] newArray = new String[4];
```

These things are basically the same. The latter tells the compiler "Give me room for 4 strings". In the former you give it 4 strings and it makes room for them. So that's not really necesarry, but correct.

```
    for(int b = 0; b < newArray.length; b++) {
        for(int a = 3; a < -1; a--) {
            newArray[b] = originalArray[a];
        }
    }
```

This piece of code is quite wrong as well. You walk over your array in the outer loop. And for each element you try to loop again. That is not needed either. Even so, your loop goes from 3 to 2 to ... But the condition is "as long as a is smaller than -1". It is not smaller than `-1` to start with, so this loop will never execute.

Answer (score 0):

You have big problems in your code here:

```
for(int b = 0; b < newArray.length; b++) {
        for(int a = 3; a < -1; a--) {
            newArray[b] = originalArray[a];
        }
}
```

With "a < -1" you probably wanted "a > -1" otherwise the inner loop does not start. But most importantly you have two nested loops (two for loops) which doesn't make sense, you need only one for loop two reverse an array and you don't even need the new array to put the result:

```
for (i = 0; i < originalArray.length / 2; i++) {
  int temp = originalArray[i];
  originalArray[i] = originalArray[originalArray.length - 1 - i];
  originalArray[originalArray.length - 1 - i] = temp;
}
```

This for loop works from both sides of the array inwards replacing the positions.

When you reach code mastery (or are not required to provide your own algorithm) you'll just use:

```
Collections.reverse()
```

:)